# Is there any difference between KDE and Kubuntu installation on Ubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

Is there any difference between KDE and Kubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kde is just a desktop environment like gnome, unity, xfce etc. kubuntu is using kde as default intead of gnome or unity. you can also install kde in ubuntu

> sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop

it will install kde with some base apps, then you can chose between unity and kde on login screen

Answer (score 1):

I guess KDE is a desktop manager while Kubuntu is an official Ubuntu release using the KDE desktop manger.

Comment: If I want to Install KDE, should I Install kubuntu using Synaptic ?

Comment: No need at all. :) You just need to install kubuntu-plasma-desktop. Please refer to this http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/kde

Answer (score 1):

**KDE** is a desktop environment build on the OS , to be more precise you can install **KDE** on any Linux distributions like **OPENSUSE** , **REDHAT**......and also in Windows .

**Ubuntu** have their thing as Unity while we still can install **GNOME** and **KDE** desktop environment to work with .

It's all left for you to make sure with what you are comfortable and see it in your desktop . Give a try for all these things and find out your comfortable zone

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant diffrences

kde is the desktop environment and
kubuntu is the official ubuntu spin with kde as the default de instead of unity

when you are installing kde in ubuntu (via apt-get install kubuntu-desktop) It install kde along side gnome/unity apps(ie it will not replace unity )